# Send/Receive Intents in the same class

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

Simple question, Is it possible to `send/receive` intents in the same class through `LocalBroadcastReceiver`? If yes can you show me an example?

Comment: Do you want to send an intent for the class itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, LocalBroadcastReceiver works everywhere. Here's an example for an `Activity`:

```
BroadcastReceiver localBroadcastReciever = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Log.d("BroadcastReceiver", "Message received " + intent.getAction());
    }
};

@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    final LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager =
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
    final IntentFilter localFilter = new IntentFilter();
    localFilter.addAction("com.my.package.intent.ACTION_NAME_HERE");
    localBroadcastManager.registerReceiver(localBroadcastReceiver, localFilter);
}

@Override
protected void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    final LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager =
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
    // Make sure to unregister!!
    localBroadcastManager.unregisterReceiver(localBroadcastReceiver);
}
```

Somewhere, either in the same `Activity` or elsewhere in your application (it doesn't matter):

```
final LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager =
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context);
localBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(new Intent("com.my.package.intent.ACTION_NAME_HERE"));
```

You can, of course, use `intent.putExtra` to add any additional data or use multiple actions to differentiate broadcast messages.