# Permissin Problem in manifest in intent for broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest, android-permissions, intentfilter

I really searched for the solution but none of them worked, one of them seemed working but this time, error occurs in another place.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.ordulou.myapplication">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver" android:enabled="true" 
    android:exported="true" 
    android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
</manifest>
```

This is the receiver class:

```
package com.example.ordulou.myapplication;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String TAG = "Message recieved";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Bundle pudsBundle = intent.getExtras();
    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) pudsBundle.get("pdus");
    SmsMessage messages = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]);

    // Start Application's  MainActivty activity
    Intent smsIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

    smsIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    smsIntent.putExtra("MessageNumber", messages.getOriginatingAddress());
    smsIntent.putExtra("Message", messages.getMessageBody());
    context.startActivity(smsIntent);
    Toast.makeText(context, "SMS Received From 
                   :"+messages.getOriginatingAddress()+"\n"+ 
                    messages.getMessageBody(), 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //Toast.makeText(context, "Wifi toggled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

i really got crazy, I tried the most basic steps in a new project, it does not work neither,
what I tried so far:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SMS_RECEIVE);*/

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] 
permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
             super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, 
             grantResults);
if (requestCode == MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SMS_RECEIVE) {
// YES!!
Log.i("TAG", "MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SMS_RECEIVE --> YES");
}
}
```

Comment: What is the problem, exactly?

Comment: sorry, i forget to tell the problem :). problem is that receiver does not work,

Comment: actually, "ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(...)" started to work now with another device. but still it asks the use to permit the device to read sms messages, i am looking for a solution that does it automatically.

Comment: Well, that's what's needed, at least since Marshmallow, if your `targetSdkVersion` is 23 or above. If you don't request that permission at runtime, the only other thing you could do is to direct the user to manually enable it on your app's Permissions page in the device Settings.

Comment: woaww, that really helped and satisfied. now i get the permsision but something is wrong with the code, when i send message to emualtor, it starts the main activity from beginning.

Comment: now i cannot pass the content of the message received to main activity

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, exactly, but a relatively simple way to send data from a manifest-registered Receiver to a running `Activity` is by using [`LocalBroadcastManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager). There's a general example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15316479). The first code block would be in your `Activity`, and the second block is what would be in your `SmsReceiver`.

Comment: thanks, when i fail to fix the receiver problem, i started to check content://sms/inbox periodically, i will look what you suggest, i really appriciate you for sharing your ideas with me. have a nice life.